# Binding Viewbag Data to Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a List in my controller which is being of type Student(class in the model)

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Student> obj = new List<Student>() {
                new Student() { ID=1,Name="titi",Address="bbsr"},
                new Student() { ID=1,Name="titi1",Address="bbsr"},
                new Student() { ID=1,Name="titi2",Address="bbsr"}
            };

            ViewBag.data = obj;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I am using Angular JS **(Beginner to Angular JS)**

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Index</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="EFView">

 @{ var a = ViewBag.data;}
   <div ng-init="init(@Html.Raw(a)">
       <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="x in a">
               <td >
                   {{x.ID}}
               </td>
               <td>
                   {{x.Name}}
               </td>
               <td>
                   {{x.Address}}
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Not getting the output as expected.. where & what I am missing, I tried with all trial

Comment: If you are beginner at angular would urge you to separate front end from back end with respect to data. Create API endpoints  and use `$http` (ajax) to retrieve the data. As for current issue...what does actual page source show for `ng-init` value ? you don't seem to be serializing json

Comment: it's a simple list , no Json. viewbag having list data & want to show it.

Comment: Browser and angular don't have any idea what a viewbag is. To pass data to `ng-init` as shown you would need to print json. You are coupling your angular to MVC too tightly though and there is no need for it

Comment: Do you mean , what ever data we need to pass to `ng-init` , need to convert to json only?

Comment: Yes.... but ultimately this is not what `ng-init` is even intended for and you should separate server data from view completely